# Парсинг хэдэр файлов

Tags: c++

Есть такая задача: пройтись по хэдэр файлу и записать в список все методы класса, определенные в хэдэре, при этом отделить чистые виртуальные, виртуальные и обычные методы. Также у каждого метода взять возвращаемое значение и занести его в отдельный список.

Так вот: как это сделать универсально? Всмысле перед названием функции может стоять макрос (который не должен никуда включаться), в самом классе межет стоять макрос вида `MAC()` и тоже не должен включатьс и т.д. Наверняка есть какие-то утилиты для этого.

Comment: Пропустить через `g++ -E`?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте clang, который умеет делать ast дерево. Естественно, исходники должны компилироваться.  На [хабре](https://habr.com/post/320074/) есть куча статей.

Хотя вполне возможно, что даже консольного вывода может хватить

```
clang -std=c++11 -Xclang -ast-dump /путь/к/файлу/cpp -I/путь/к/директории/с/include/файлами -Dнужные_макросы -fsyntax-only
```